# How to remove this "Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' " error? (Navigation View with fragments)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-navigationview

This is my Program of NavigationView with Fragment:

```
package com.example.anubhasharma.assign;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public BottomNavigationView mMainNav;
public FrameLayout mMainFrame;

public HomeFragment homeFragment;
public OfferFragment offerFragment;
public ProfileFragment profileFragment;
public HistoryFragment historyFragment;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMainFrame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
    mMainNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_nav);

    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    offerFragment = new OfferFragment();
    historyFragment = new HistoryFragment();
    profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();

    mMainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.nav_home :
                    mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRed);
                    setFragment(homeFragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_profile :
                    mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRed);
                    setFragment(profileFragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_offer :
                    mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRed);
                    setFragment(offerFragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.nav_history :
                    mMainNav.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorRed);
                    setFragment(historyFragment);
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {


    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

}

But I'm Facing this error:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Here is build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.anubhasharma.assign"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

This app was running before. I have tried so many solutions to remove this error. So please help.
Thank You

Comment: Check your jdk location, is it there?

Comment: Yes, it is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the "Build" tab at the bottom and check the complier output. If you haven't update to the last version of Android Studio (I'm using 3.1.2). Then you can see the complier output in a structured way